# Disable yeoman telemetry

Tags: yeoman, telemetry, yo

I'm on linux. I installed `yo` (v 4.3.0) and ran it.

It showed a prompt asking me to opt in for telemetry. I didn't answer in time and it moved past that prompt. When I run yo now, it doesn't show that prompt anymore.

How do I permanently disable telemetry?